# x-axis is shifted to the right?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The x-axis is shifted to the right and not sure why. I've used `plt.xlim(left=0)` but the distribution line still comes from the negative side even though there are no negative values?

Here is the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))

# vals will be used to store the index of all the loan_type that equal 'TR'
vals = []
my_vals = []

for x in range(len(df['LOAN_TYPE'])):
    if (df['LOAN_TYPE'][x] == 'TR' or df['LOAN_TYPE'][x] == 'TOFR') and df['PAY_FREQUENCY'][x] == 'M':
        vals = df['LOAN_TYPE'].index[x]
        my_vals.append(vals)

sns.distplot(df['# Payments Made'][my_vals],bins = 60)
#plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['# Payments Made'][my_vals]),max(df['# Payments Made'][my_vals])+1,1))
plt.axvline(np.mean(df['# Payments Made'][my_vals]), color="r", linestyle="--");
```

[image]

Comment: That can’t be your complete code.  What made the blue line?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied the wrong part of the code. I added the correct code now.

Comment: Looks like you are confused by what a KDE is; see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109549/negative-density-for-non-negative-variables).